# unable to start grunt - "TypeError: grunt.registerHelper is not a function" on ubuntu 16

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Unable to start grunt

Trying to run `grunt serve` on a mean project but instead getting this:

`Running "serve" task
Loading "clean.js" tasks...ERROR`

> > TypeError: grunt.registerHelper is not a function

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Warning: grunt.helper is not a function Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Execution Time (2017-11-05 07:32:02 UTC+1)
loading tasks        814ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 90%
serve                 63ms  ▇▇▇ 7%
loading grunt-clean   14ms  ▇ 2%
Total 900ms

any thoughts

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
npm install
```

& if always persist try:

```
bower update
npm update
```